# Modem and internet: fixing low connectivity and latency spikes?

Tags: networking, modem, latency

So I got a tp-link TD-8817 adsl2+ modem at times the connection is intermittent. Right out of the box it does´t connect so to set it up following the quick connection wizard:

1. Pick the time zone
2. Choose dynamic ip (thats how my ISP works)
3. Set VPI to 0 and VCI to 33 and then set the Connection Type: to bridged IP LLC

Lately when I get bad connectivity I ping the modem and it shows the following pattern over and over.

`Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=253
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=5ms TTL=253
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=253
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=253
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=166ms TTL=253
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=253
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=253
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=253
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=253
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=253
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=5ms TTL=253
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=253
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=253
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=253
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1742ms TTL=253
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=3500ms TTL=253
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=158ms TTL=253
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=253
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=253
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=253
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=253
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=253
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=253
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=5ms TTL=253
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=253
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=253
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=741ms TTL=253
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1738ms TTL=253
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=2997ms TTL=253
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=404ms TTL=253
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=253
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=253
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=253
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=253
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=112ms TTL=253
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=253
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=158ms TTL=253
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=253
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=6ms TTL=253
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=253
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=253
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=253
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=6ms TTL=253
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=253
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=216ms TTL=253
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1213ms TTL=253
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=3001ms TTL=253`

Pinging google goes something like this

`Reply from 172.217.11.142: bytes=32 time=106ms TTL=48
Reply from 172.217.11.142: bytes=32 time=105ms TTL=48
Reply from 172.217.11.142: bytes=32 time=108ms TTL=48
Reply from 172.217.11.142: bytes=32 time=114ms TTL=48
Reply from 172.217.11.142: bytes=32 time=114ms TTL=48
Reply from 172.217.11.142: bytes=32 time=107ms TTL=48
Reply from 172.217.11.142: bytes=32 time=108ms TTL=48
Reply from 172.217.11.142: bytes=32 time=105ms TTL=48
Reply from 172.217.11.142: bytes=32 time=104ms TTL=48
Reply from 172.217.11.142: bytes=32 time=106ms TTL=48
Reply from 172.217.11.142: bytes=32 time=105ms TTL=48
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.1.1: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.1: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.1: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.1: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.1: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.1: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.1: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.1: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.1: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.1: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.1: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.1: Destination host unreachable.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Reply from 172.217.11.142: bytes=32 time=104ms TTL=48
Reply from 172.217.11.142: bytes=32 time=109ms TTL=48
Reply from 172.217.11.142: bytes=32 time=107ms TTL=48
Reply from 172.217.11.142: bytes=32 time=146ms TTL=48
Reply from 172.217.11.142: bytes=32 time=267ms TTL=48
Reply from 172.217.11.142: bytes=32 time=118ms TTL=48
Reply from 172.217.11.142: bytes=32 time=117ms TTL=48
Reply from 172.217.11.142: bytes=32 time=104ms TTL=48`

What I have tried so far.

- Turning on and off
- Factory reset
- Changing adsl modes to auto, G.DMT and G.Lite
- Done the test both connected directly and trough the wifi router
- Changed the cables and microfilter
- Connected it directly to the main phone outlet with no microfilter.
- Doing ipconfig /renew /release /flushdns
- Made sure my pc was the only device on the network and no background downloads were happening like torrents
- Test with both a pc with win10 and a laptop with linux

Also in the past it gave me problems where the ping stayed around 2000ms+ for long times even after reboots.

Any inputs on how can I fix this or any particular problem I showed? Thx in advance!

Comment: If the problem happens while pinging the router directly, then it probably isn't WAN-side (but it may be that the device is busy trying to renegotiate). Try to see if you can set up the router to not attempt to connect to wan, and then disconnect the WAN side completely and then see if you can reproduce the ping response issue without any WAN connection. This way you can rule out the DSL entirely as a point of failure.

Comment: I'm not sure i follow you, did you meant WLAN? because I understand the WAN is the wide area network

Comment: I meant WAN. The first principle in troubleshooting is to eliminate possible causes. If you eliminate the WAN as a feature entirely, and the problem goes away, then you now know that the DSL or an interaction with the DSL is the problem. If I read it correctly, your ping spikes and timeouts happen when pinging the device directly, so if the problem is the device (the DSL is fine) then until you can decouple the DSL from the setup, then pinging outside the LAN will not yield useful information.

Comment: And "yes" the next step would be to disable the wireless radio. Just don't do it all at once: you either want to disable everything until you stop seeing the issue and turn them on one at a time until it starts, *or* turn off one thing at a time until it stops happening. Otherwise you won't know.

Answer (score 0):

Followed Yorik's advice and tried everything without my network switch and other devices connected to it and now it all settled cannot point my finger in a particular thing but it solved my issue!